# How to replace all HTML tags with src id

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to python. I'm trying to read mails using imaplib, post to reading i'm sending the mail content to an API.

The challenge is i need to remove the attachment tag i.e., if it is an image i need to replace it with image src instead of img tags.

in a brief if the html string consists of tags with src, the entire tag to be replaced with src.

from this to

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><b>Step 2</b>: If you select &#8220;<b>NO</b>&#8221; option it will ask you to select Virtual or Physical<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><img width="614" height="101" id="Picture_x0020_19" src="cid:image002.png@01D52B83.A2B838F0"><o:p></o:p></p>
```

this

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><b>Step 2</b>: If you select &#8220;<b>NO</b>&#8221; option it will ask you to select Virtual or Physical<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">image002.png@01D52B83.A2B838F0<o:p></o:p></p>
```

Comment: So you have The text in Python and then want to modify it and then send it to an API?

Comment: @Enzy yes.. i am saving all the content of HTML into a string and later sending it to API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace_with()` function to do that. To select all tags with attribute `src` you can use CSS selector `"[src]"`:

```
data = '''
<p class="MsoNormal"><b>Step 2</b>: If you select &#8220;<b>NO</b>&#8221; option it will ask you to select Virtual or Physical<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><img width="614" height="101" id="Picture_x0020_19" src="cid:image002.png@01D52B83.A2B838F0"><o:p></o:p></p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.select('[src]'):
    tag.replace_with(tag['src'])

for p in soup.select('p'):
    print(p)
```

Prints:

```
<p class="MsoNormal"><b>Step 2</b>: If you select “<b>NO</b>” option it will ask you to select Virtual or Physical<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal">cid:image002.png@01D52B83.A2B838F0<o:p></o:p></p>
```